# How to check the android id of onTouch listener of guester in side my custom adapter

Tags: android

In my application i need double tap over the imageview, for that i implemented gesture. Here i used too image views i can't identify which image is clicked its image one or image too. I implemented this code in my custom adapter. Here is my code for your reference,

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

holder.imgOne.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        holder.imgTwo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        //////////////////////

            @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
        Log.e("DOUBLE TAP", "WORKING");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("SINGLE TAB CLICKED", e.getSource() + "");
        // new PopupImageDialog(assingValue.leftPicThumb, "leftPic").execute();
        return true;
    }
```

If it we implement `onClickListener()` means we can get the Id, here how can i get the id. how can i identify the button touch. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try MotionEvent.getSource() ?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: I got same id for both

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe it some kind of dirty hack but I hope it will work.

```
holder.imgOne.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                event.setSource(v.getId);
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        holder.imgTwo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                event.setSource(v.getId);
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Then use getSource() to get view id.

Comment: thanks for this, let you know it's working.. also how can i implement single tab and double tap on the same view (imageview)

Comment: I think there are no way to implement both tap & double tap from your code - you handle simple touch and then send an event to gesture detector. So it's became a your headache - define where was single or double tap. Sorry.

Comment: is there any other approach for doing my need